# Converting assetBundle to GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have Loaded the Model in Unity from Server and it runs fine on editor because everything is running fine.
But when I Run it on Andriod it doesn't go forward from this line

```
GameObject temp = (GameObject)bundle.LoadAsset(assetName);
```

I have tried different approaches to do so but the result is same as it runs fine on editor but not on andriod

```
public IEnumerator DownloadAsset(WWW www, string assetName)
{
    yield return www;
    AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
    if (www.error == null)
    {
        GameObject temp = (GameObject)bundle.LoadAsset(assetName); 

        Instantiate(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use [`UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-DownloadingAssetBundle.html) instead of `WWW`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that occurs due to an exception when trying to convert the loaded Object from the Asset Bundle to a GameObject.
(This mostly happens when it the Object that is loaded is not supposed to be a GameObject)

You can try converting with the `as` keyword instead.

```
// Tries to convert to GameObject, returns null if it fails
GameObject temp = _bundle.LoadAsset(_assetName) as GameObject;

if (temp != null){
    Instantiate(temp);
} else {
    // Failed to convert to gameObject
}
```

#### Edit

Like what derHugo mentioned, you should use [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-DownloadingAssetBundle.html) instead.
(What you did was using [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html), which does not "transform" the data into an AssetBundle when downloading it.)

Following the online website, you should have this as your result:

```
   UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle("website Name to get the asset bundle");
   yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
        // Error fetching the asset bundle from the website.
    }
    else {
        AssetBundle bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(www);
        GameObject temp = bundle.LoadAsset(assetName) as GameObject;

        if (temp != null){
            Instantiate(temp);
        } else {
            // Failed to convert to gameObject
        }
    }
```

Comment: No brother still same problem it doesn't go forward from this line GameObject temp = _bundle.LoadAsset(_assetName) as GameObject;

Comment: AGUIMisc.ShowToast("1");
 GameObject temp = bundle.LoadAsset(assetName) as GameObject;
  AGUIMisc.ShowToast("2");

Comment: @optikalsapp can you check if your `_bundle` is null before you attempt to load asset? that might an issue too.

Comment: yeah it is null

Comment: @optikalsapp then the main problem should lie in `AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;`, your `www.assetBundle` was null. What is calling `DownloadAsset` function and passing in the WWW?

Comment: WWW www1 = new WWW(url);
StartCoroutine(DownloadAsset(www1,asset));

Comment: @optikalsapp edited my answer, as @derHugo mentioned, you were using the wrong class. `WWW` is not directly suitable to download AssetBundles

Comment: UnityWebRequest www1 = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(url);
    StartCoroutine(DownloadAsset(www1,splitArray[1]));  I used this still no luck

Comment: and in download asset bundle function  yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        AssetBundle bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(www);

Comment: unityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle is absolete so I used UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(url)    still no luck